# Can I use gpg on both Ubuntu and Windows to encrypt my files

Tags: software-recommendation, windows, encryption, gnupg, certificates

I have a private gpg key for Ubuntu.

My question is: How can I use same encryption key for both Windows and Ubuntu?

If I use gpg in Ubuntu, can I use that same gpg key with Windows or vice versa? Or more simply: If I sign a file with gpg in Ubuntu, how can i use that file in Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer of the question: `Can I use same encryption key for both Windows and Ubuntu?` is Yes. You can definitely use the same encryption key on both Windows and Ubuntu.

`How` part of the question requires some more info:

### To use gpg key on Ubuntu

Open `password and encryption keys` and import your gpg private to the keystore.

then you can use this key to sign and encrypt files you want. Here is a [good tutorial about using gpg](http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/howtos.en.html) on Ubuntu.

### To use gpg on Windows

To use the same gpg key on Windows download a suitable tool from [this site](http://www.gpg4win.org/download.html). After installation is complete you can import the gpg private key into your keystore and use that key to sign your files. The documentation is [here](http://www.gpg4win.org/documentation.html)