# Are there any video or Audio encryption software avialable in ubuntu 12.04 repositories

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, video, encryption

I have to submit my Video presentation and other pptx files so i need them to be encrypted. .

Is there any Software or Application available in Ubuntu 12.04 Repositories for doing this.

I tried this [Link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-files-with-a-password.html) which uses GPG file encryption method , but however , the platform to be presented on might be Windows , so i am not sure whether to use this or not, also after using will this work or not.

I want to mention i am not talking about [DVD encryption](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500/how-can-i-play-encrypted-dvd-movies) , but rather Format-wise encryption.

For example - .avi, .mp4,.flv.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit system.

**NOTE:**

I just realized i can use secure archiving like zip or rar, but that would defy the need for such Encryption application.

Also i can rename them to any unsuspecting file , and removing the extension  .For Example : .recycle.[For the time being i will use one of these methods , but will keep an eye for such app if available, so i am not closing this question until then]

After searching i found there are Windows software available for that purpose, but in Linux i was unsuccessful.

Comment: What do you mean by encryption exactly, or why you need them to be encrypted? You mean DRM?

Comment: Encryption in a way that they need to ask password for accessing them.

Comment: Yes ,open for any open-source suggestion .

Comment: I meant , if i packed them in password protected Zip or rar archive that will be a alternate solution , but crackable though using Zip password recovery like software .If i stick to it for such encryption needs , then i will isolate the need of Video encryption like utilities. I apologise if my English is not that clear , you are free to edit it .Also for now i am using this archiving method , so i am keeping this Q open if, if not suitable please post so , so i can delete it.

Comment: The old zip encryption (ZipCrypto) is easily broken; I don't know about RAR, **but** both ZIP (WinZip on Windows) and 7-zip support AES-256 encryption which cannot be easily broken (unless you use a short password, dictionary word, etc.). I have just the solution for your answer, I'll add it in a little bit...

Comment: You can see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/136456/61218) , if you want to use gpg on both Windows and Linux

Comment: This unanswered question is about Ubuntu 12.04 which is EOL. OP never responded to later comments by @Anwar and appears to have lost interest.  If interest still exists it is probably best to write a new question about using modern encryption software. VTC this 5+ year old question as `not reproducible`.